Is there a tool like `dd` but respect sparse-ness of input file?
I am creating disk images with multiple ext4 partitions on it. Each ext4 partition content is created with mkfs.ext4 and the resulting filesystem image files are "sparse".
When I use dd to create a system image (with a partition table in the beginning) from all these individual file systems, then the resulting image will not be sparse anymore.
It would be wrong to use dd conv=sparse because that would make the output sparse for all-NUL output blocks. But that's not what I want. I want the output to be sparse if the input was sparse.
This is necessary, because in the end I want to be able to flash the image with bmaptool which is able to not write to the physical device those blocks which are "sparse" and thus save time when writing the image. If I would just treat all blocks that are only zeroes as sparse, then random data on the disk which was not NUL would not be overwritten which is a problem for files on the filesystem that are actually supposed to contain zeroes.
So is there a tool that does what dd does and is able to copy one file into another with a given offset but keeps those blocks that are sparse in the input file sparse in the output file?

Have you considered doing it the other way around – first creating a sparse whole-disk image, setting up a /dev/loop0, partitioning it, and then mkfs.ext4'ing each partition?

I guess an elegant solution would be to develop support for offset (like dd's seek=) in bmaptool copy.

@u1686_grawity we are creating multiple images and some partitions are always the same. That's why we want to create the partition once and then copy it onto multiple output images.

@KamilMaciorowski Yes, if nothing exists already then either what you said or teach dd how to use lseek with SEEK_DATA and SEEK_HOLE to do the copy.

I wonder: if you truncate the target file to the desired size, then use losetup --find --show --offset … --sizelimit … to map the "partition" to a loop device, then use bmaptool to write to the associated /dev/loopN – will the target file be sparse in the way you want? Note the modern losetup gives you --partscan, so if you create a partition table first then losetup --partscan … (with right --sector-size) will map all "partitions" to /dev/loopNpM special files without any need for specifying --offset and --sizelimit manually. Do your own tests.

@KamilMaciorowski That is a good idea. I'm more familiar with kpartx than with losetup so I used the former to have /dev/mapper/loop0p1 point onto the first partition of my disk image and used bmaptool to copy my partition data onto it. And yes, the underlying disk image file remains sparse as expected. The problem with this approach is, that it requires superuser privileges and I'd like to void requiring those.

Since I was unable to find a tool that works like dd but would reproduce the sparse-ness of the input in its output, I wrote a small Python script which does exactly that:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import os
import sys


def main():
    infd = os.open(sys.argv[1], os.O_RDONLY)
    inlength = os.lseek(infd, 0, os.SEEK_END)
    outfd = os.open(sys.argv[2], os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
    outlength = os.lseek(outfd, 0, os.SEEK_END)
    offset = int(sys.argv[3])
    curr = 0
    while True:
        try:
            data = os.lseek(infd, curr, os.SEEK_DATA)
        except OSError:
            # no more data
            break
        try:
            hole = os.lseek(infd, data, os.SEEK_HOLE)
        except OSError:
            # no hole afterwards, copy until EOF
            hole = inlength
        print(
            f"copying range {data}..{hole} ({100*hole/inlength:.2f}%)", file=sys.stderr
        )
        os.copy_file_range(
            infd, outfd, hole - data, offset_src=data, offset_dst=data + offset
        )
        curr = hole
    if outlength < inlength + offset:
        os.truncate(outfd, inlength + offset)
    os.close(infd)
    os.close(outfd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

According to du my final system images now only take 3.7 G of disk space instead of the full 5.1 G that the image file is sized at.
For my 3 G ext4 filesystems, the main loop above is only iterating around 500 times, so most of the time will be spent in copy_file_range() and not in Python, so I'm not worried that the code is not written in C but porting it to C would probably be trivial.
EDIT
Okay, here is a version written in C:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile outfile [offset]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int infd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (infd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    off64_t inlength = lseek64(infd, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (inlength == -1) {
        perror("lseek64");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int outfd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    if (outfd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    off64_t outlength = lseek64(outfd, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (outlength == -1) {
        perror("lseek64");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    long long offset = 0;
    if (argc == 4) {
        offset = strtoll(argv[3], NULL, 10);
        if (errno != 0) {
            perror("strtoll");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    off64_t curr = 0;
    while (true) {
        off64_t data = lseek64(infd, curr, SEEK_DATA);
        if (data == -1) {
            break;
        }
        off64_t hole = lseek64(infd, data, SEEK_HOLE);
        if (hole == -1) {
            hole = inlength;
        }
        off64_t off_out = data + offset;
        ssize_t ret = copy_file_range(infd, &data, outfd, &off_out, hole - data, 0);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("copy_file_range");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        curr = hole;
    }
    if (outlength < inlength + offset) {
        int ret = ftruncate(outfd, inlength + offset);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("ftruncate");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    close(infd);
    close(outfd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

